# Azure ML Error: AADSTS70016: OAuth 2.0 device flow error. Authorization is pending. Continue polling

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Hi I am trying to run an experiment using a compute instance through Azureml SDK using the code bellow:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment, ScriptRunConfig
from azureml.core.environment import Environment

ws=Workspace.from_config(path='My path')

cluster = ws.compute_targets['My compute target']

myenv = Environment.get(workspace=ws, name="myenv")

new_experiment= Experiment(workspace=ws,
                           name='Name')

script_config =ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='.',  
                               script='Script to Run.py',
                               compute_target=cluster,
                               environment=myenv
                                )


new_run=new_experiment.submit(config=script_config)
```

After over 15 minutes of waiting I get the error 'Error: AADSTS70016: OAuth 2.0 device flow error. Authorization is pending' , if I run the same code but with the computer target as 'local' it runs right,

I know that it is an autetication problem, but it is not clear to me how can I solve it. Thanks for any advice

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52252#issuecomment-613254410  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code#authenticating-the-user, and https://clemenssiebler.com/azure-active-directory-authentication-using-oauth-2-0-device-code-flow-with-azure-bot-service-and-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

It's suggestable to recheck the configuration settings. The below link can help to configure the settings.

https://joonasw.net/view/device-code-flow

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code